# QGIS layer visibility

Tags: qgis, layers

I am attempting to create a simple distribution map.

I have created a vector layer by importing a table in .tsv file format consisting of a list of named points with latitude & longitude in decimal degrees plus heights. CRS is EPSG:27700 (OSGB 1936 British National Grid), the same as the other layers in the project. I can see the points displayed in the correct positions relative to one another by highlighting and zooming to the layer, but I cannot see any of the other layers. The attributes table has data in it which corresponds to the ’tsv spreadsheet from which it was derived.

I have also saved the file as a .shp file; again, I can zoom to that layer and see the points, and the attribute table looks OK, but I still can’t see any of the other layers, except for the .tsv layer from which the new .shp file was derived. To return to the other layers I have to select one of them and click the zoom to layer tool. But then I can’t see the new layer.

I’ve had several attempts at importing, including importing using CRS ESPG:3857 (WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator). Result is the same. I have CRS transformation ’on the fly’ enabled in Project Properties.

How do I solve this problem?

I am using QGIS 2.12.1 on a Mac (OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Reproject layer tool from the Toolbox (enabled from Processing--> Toolbox):
[image: qgis_toolbox_example_reproject_layer]

I was able to reproject a .shp file from UTM 31N to WGS 84 without any problem using it.